# How to access json file in Angular4

Tags: json, angular

I want to **acccess data.json** file in **myservice.service.ts** .

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve it?

> Directory structure

[image: Directory Structure]

> myserivce.service.ts file

[image: myService]

> Getting error like this

[image: error]

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Try to change the private to public for your _url variable in your service file.

Comment: it didn't work @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use URL like `data.json` and Put the `data.json` file in your `src/` directory. It will work fine.

**OR**

Use URL like `assets/data.json` and Put the `data.json` file in your `src/assets/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. The `data.json` file has to exist on the server hosting the web application.
2. The URL you provide `$http` is **not** relative to the service or component that is executing the request (or request chain). You have to specify the absolute url which would be

   ```
   private _url = '/src/app/data.json';
   ```